# moment().add changes previously set variable

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a function that should return two variables, `thisYear` and `nextYear` when I pass a date to the function. However, when I call `.add` on `date` it is changing the value of `thisYear` even though `thisYear` was already set.

**Function and call**

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/29945/

```
var someDate = moment()
thisYearAndNextYear(someDate)

function thisYearAndNextYear(date) {
  const thisYear = date
  console.log("thisYear = " + thisYear);
  const nextYear = date.add(1, 'year')
  console.log("nextYear = " + nextYear);
  console.log("thisYear (after nextYear set) = " + thisYear);
}
```

**Output**

```
thisYear = 1522021438255
nextYear = 1553557438255
thisYear (after nextYear set) = 1553557438255  // ISSUE: this should still be 1522021438255
```

**Does anyone understand how to prevent this odd behavior such that `thisYear` retains its initial value?**

Comment: That is how moment works.  It has cloning options, but if you want a library that never modifies your dates, you might check out [date-fp](https://github.com/cullophid/date-fp).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference. When you pass an variable referencing an object to a function, that function still gets a reference to the original object. You can think of it like this: variables for non-primitives (such as objects) reference *memory addresses*, and those memory addresses get passed around.

So, when you call `add` on the moment object, the object gets mutated.

If you want to clone the moment object so you can operate on a copy of it:

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/

call the `.clone()` method.

```
const nextYear = date.clone();
nextYear.add(1, 'year')
```